# How to see data in ParseObject in Parse Explorer?

Tags: android, parse-platform

[image]

This is screenshot of my Parse Explorer. It has two objects **GameScore** and **TestObject**. These are created using Parse SDK for Android. How can I see the data in these objects in Parse Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with your question. I think this might be your solution. You can browse the data in those object in the "Core" Menu. "Core" menu can be found at the top of the web page. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Yeah...I was asking this. Thanks for help :)